# Executing powershell file in Jenkins fails with `xx.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system`

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I recently switched the Jenkins service (Windows) to a functional account rather to let Jenkins run as `Local System Account`. However now the script will not run and fails with

```
powershell.exe : & : File D:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\im-server_feature_os-jenkins-aaw@tmp\durable-42a4a855\powershellScript.ps1 
At D:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\im-server_feature_os-jenkins-aaw@tmp\durable-42a4a855\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
+ & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (& : File D:\jen...hellScript.ps1 :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
cannot be loaded. The file 
D:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\im-server_feature_os-jenkins-aaw@tmp\durable-42a4a855\powershellScript.ps1 is not 
digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and 

setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

At line:1 char:3

+ & 'd:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\im-server_feature_os-jenkins-aa ...

+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

The exact call is as follows:

```
command = '.\\build.ps1 -Project "IM-Server"'
log = powershell returnStdout: true, script: command
```

The remote policy for the user is `RemoteSigned` - which should be fine as the script is anyway locally written.

More interestingly the Jenkins itself calls the script with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`.

```
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm...
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Is there NTFS ADS containing [zone identifier](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378446) on the file? Unblock-File would remove those.

Comment: No there is not. And if I switch the Jenkins service to run as my personal user account, the script seems to be executed - to say I have local admin rights. But still calls the script with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypas` so actually I would expect the script to run

Comment: The error is actually very specific and it tells you exactly where to find the solution as well in the error message http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170